# Order of evaluation: undefined behavior? or compiler defect?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, ansi-c, unspecified-behavior

I am getting wrong asm code for the below test code from the C compiler. 
Is this due to undefined behavior ?

```
void SimulatedTest(void)
{                                   
    if ( (a) || (b && c || d) == 1 )
    {
        i = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 4;
    }
}
```

What standard says:

*6.5.16 Assignment operators*

> The order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified. If an attempt
>   is made to modify the result of an assignment operator or to access it
>   after the next sequence point, **the behavior is undefined**

*C Operator Precedence rule*

> 1. ()
> 2. ==
> 3. || &&

For the problem case: if ( (a) || (b && c || d) == 1 )
Compiler evaluates the expression in the below order and generates wrong code

> 1.(b && c || d)                     -->R1
>
> 2.R1 == 1                           -->R2
>
> 3.(a) || R2

However compiler ***generates correct code*** for the below cases

**Case1:**. When there is no relational '==' operation

```
if ( (a) || (b && c || d) )//compiler generates expected code
```

**Case2:** When Parentheses is added for logical OR operation

```
if ( ((a) || (b && c || d)) == 1 )//compiler generates expected code
```

**Case3:** no parentheses used between operations

```
if ( a || b && c || d == 1 )//compiler generates expected code
```

Would like to know whether the problem case falls under undefined behavior category or not.

Regards,

Mac

Comment: Just a remark about your _C Operator Precedence rule_: `&&` has a  higher precedence than `||` so, they don't have to be on same line

Comment: You seem to lack a set of parentheses if you want to get your 'expected result'

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: If you think any answer answered your question please consider accepting it (the grey checkmark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 7):

Equality operator `==` has higher precedence than the logical or `||` operator. Therefore the compiler is correct and there is no undefined behavior.

The evaluation is identical to:

```
a || ( ( b && c || d ) == 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 if ( (a) || (b && c || d) == 1 )
```

is comparing the results of `||` with an integer which is never what you want to do.

Given the order of precedence of logical operators which is not always what people expect, it's generally safest to throw in brackets to make things clearer to the read, thus

```
 if ( (a) || ((b && c) || d) == 1 )
```

or

```
 if ( (a) || (b && (c || d)) == 1 )
```

to deal with the `&&` or `||`

and depending on what you expect the == to be comparing with (if you *really* want to do that, which I doubt)

```
 if ( (a) || ((b && c || d) == 1) )
```

or

```
 if ( ((a) || (b && c || d)) == 1 )
```

But the compiler is compiling right. It's just not terribly obvious what is meant to be happening to the human mind.